# Нужен видео компрессор, совместимый с DirectShow.

Tags: c#, directshow, видео, visual-studio

Сам я разрабатываю приложение, в котором доступна запись с web-камеры.

(Visual Studio 2008, C#)

Требуемый размер сжатия: примерно 10 сек = 1 мб.
Из тех компрессоров, что нашел я, подходит только один из [DivX Codec pack](http://www.divx.com/en/software/divx-plus/codec-pack), но он, судя по всему, платный + ставится только в комплекте с кучей всякого ненужного лично мне мусора через DivXInstaller.exe. Хотя в DivX Control Panel напротив кодеков написано: trial 15 days left. И эти 15 days у меня висят уже недели две…

Еще есть неплохой вариант: VP40® Compressor. Степень сжатия, где-то 1 секунда – 1 мб. С ним есть непонятные проблемы на Windows XP, что именно там переклинило, я не знаю, но видео не записывается. Буду разбираться. Сам я тестирую на Windows 7.

Те вопросы, который есть у меня сейчас:

1. Есть ли нормальный установщик для
       DivX, который установит только
       кодеки для видео, а не будет тащить
       200 мб из сети?
2. Какие есть другие хорошие видео
       компрессоры, совместимые с
       DirectShow? Те, что есть по
       умолчанию (всякие Microsoft Video 1,
       DV Video Encoder, и.т.п ) обладают
       либо совершенно смешной степенью
       сжатия, либо очень плохим качеством
       записанного видео.
3. Ну и да, компрессор должен быть бесплатным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну что ж, подведем некоторые итоги. По результатам тестов, был выбран VP40® Compressor для Windows 7 и Windows Vista. На Win XP, как оказалось, этот компрессор не работает, лол )).
Для Windows XP пришлось выбрать компромиссный вариант: Microsoft Video 1. Качество записанного видео конечно у него ахавое. Ответы со StackOverflow не помогли )). Всем спасибо.

Comment: Эээ, товарищи, это что, чтобы закрыть СВОЙ вопрос я должен набрать 250 репутации? Не кажется ли вам, что это как-то странно? Может стоит убрать бонус в 50 очков за ответ на свой вопрос, но сделать возможность закрыть его без лимита на репутацию?

Comment: @Olter, спасибо за ваш отзыв, передал администрации.

Answer (score 2):

Кодек, который дает сносное качество, при этом бесплатный, работающий стабильно и, более того, даже имеется в наличии во всех версиях Windows - это Windows Media Video 9. Так как он доступен [в виде DMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819505), то его можно также использовать и в DirectShow. Можно писать в WMV/ASF файлы, можно в AVI.

Популярные из сторонних - [h264vfw](http://sourceforge.net/projects/x264vfw/) (по бесплатности есть вопросы), [theora](http://xiph.org/dshow/). Что касается DivX, то вроде как Xvid был доступен в аскетичном формате без мусора, хотя он (MPEG-4 Part 2) уже по большей части - история и уж относительно него так Windows Media Video будет уж попредпочтительней.

Еще один вариант, заслуживающий упоминания, это Motion JPEG кодек. Видео в этом формате, конечно, не сравнится по качеству сжатия с кодеками, условно скажем, высшей лиги, однако какая никакая совместимость между устройствами и программами имеется, формат этот очень прост в использовании, стандартная реализация - убогая, но есть. Отличием данного формата будет то, что каждый кадр сжимается независимо и, соответственно, нет артефактов между кадрами, специфичных для [temporal compression] форматов.